# Reversed Path Animation in Blend

Tags: xaml, animation, expression-blend

I have a path animation in Blend of something moving in a circle I created by using the shortcut to convert a shape into a motion path.  When the animation begins it moves clockwise, but I want it to start counterclockwise.  Is there any way in XAML to change that direction, without having using autoreverse?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you to essentially reverse your animation but without autoreverse.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294966%28v=expression.40%29.aspx

Comment: ah, reverse the whole storyboard! but what if I have other stuff in my storyboard?

Comment: You might consider breaking them out separately then, except that may not be necessary. Is it huge? Maybe want to let someone peek at it?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  The path has start and end points even when they're closed shapes, and that's where the animation starts and ends.  So just transform the path.    breaking up the storyboard would work too, but just moving the points around seems less challenging

Comment: Ah ya I really should have suggested that too! Haha as long as you got your remedy. :)